# Get type of object and name of the property from a comparison in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the definition of classes:

```
class Child:
    pass
class Parent:
    child = Child()
```

where `Child` can have different `args` and `kwargs`, so please do not consider this notation: `child = Child(Parent, 'child')`

After an assignment like:

```
result = Parent.child > 1
```

where `Parent` is a type (not an instance)

**result** should be:

```
{
    'type': Parent,
    'property': 'child',
    'action': '>',
    'value': 1,
}
```

I'm not sure if it's possible at all, but is there anybody who knows a trick?

Comment: Yeah that is possible. Any attempt from your side?

Comment: No, there's no trick. You have to actually code it to do that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've made a few attempts, but none of them worked out, so I didn't publish them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references:

```
class BaseChild:
    type = None
    property = None

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return {
            'type': self.type,
            'property': self.property,
            'action': '>',
            'value': other,
        }


class MetaParent(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

        # This is the needed trick
        for name, attr in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(attr, BaseChild):
                attr.type = cls
                attr.property = name

        return cls


class SomeChild(BaseChild):
    pass


class Parent(metaclass=MetaParent):
    first_child = SomeChild()


print(Parent.first_child > 1)
```

Result:

```
{'type': <class '__main__.Parent'>, 'value': 1, 'property': 'first_child', 'action': '>'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to store the parent reference in the child object explicitly. The `>` operator can be hooked into with the [`__gt__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__).

Since you are producing output that contains *dynamic* information on the `child` attribute, you could produce a *dynamic* child object, using the [`__getattr__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), which is called whenever an otherwise non-existing attribute is accessed:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent_type, attr_name):
        self._parent_type = parent_type
        self._parent_attr_name = attr_name

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return {
            'type': self._parent_type,
            'property': self._parent_attr_name,
            'action': '>',
            'value': other,
        }

class Parent:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return Child(type(self), name)
```

Demo:

```
>>> Parent().child > 1
{'type': <class '__main__.Parent'>, 'property': 'child', 'action': '>', 'value': 1}
```

If `Parent` *must* be a class (why?) then use a fixed attribute (`child = Child(Parent, 'child')`), or use a metaclass:

```
class ParentMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        return Child(cls, name)

class Parent(metaclass=ParentMeta):
    pass
```

at which point you get the same effect, but without creating an instance:

```
>>> Parent.child > 1
{'type': <class '__main__.Parent'>, 'property': 'child', 'action': '>', 'value': 1}
```

As of Python 3.6 onwards, you also use the [`__set_name__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) to capture the type of the class on which your attribute is defined:

```
class Child:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, attr_name):
        self._parent_type = owner
        self._parent_attr_name = attr_name

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return {
            'type': self._parent_type,
            'property': self._parent_attr_name,
            'action': '>',
            'value': other,
        }
```

Note that these attributes are not set in the `__init__`! You create the child object as an attribute on the class, at which point the `__set_name__` method is called automatically. The output is again the same:

```
>>> class Parent:
...     child = Child()
...
>>> Parent.child > 1
{'type': <class '__main__.Parent'>, 'property': 'child', 'action': '>', 'value': 1}
```

Note that *subclasses* are not going to be reflected in the parent type; you'd have to use the [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) to capture the current type each time and return a wrapper object:

```
class ChildWrapper:
    def __init__(self, child, parent_type):
        self._child = child
        self._parent_type = parent_type

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._child, name)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return {
            'type': self._parent_type,
            'property': self._child._parent_attr_name,
            'action': '>',
            'value': other,
        }

class Child:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, attr_name):
        self._parent_attr_name = attr_name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return ChildWrapper(self, owner)
```

This creates a `ChildWrapper()` instance on each attribute access (on the class or an instance), and all further attribute access is delegated back to the original `Child()` instance (but note that special methods [can't be proxied this way](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)):

```
>>> class Parent:
...     child = Child()
...
>>> Parent.child
<__main__.ChildWrapper object at 0x10fc564e0>
>>> Parent.child > 1
{'type': <class '__main__.Parent'>, 'property': 'child', 'action': '>', 'value': 1}
```

Because the `ChildWrapper` is created each time based on the object it was accessed on, this works with subclassing too, tracking the *current* type:

```
>>> class Subclass(Parent):
...     pass
...
>>> Subclass.child > 1
{'type': <class '__main__.Subclass'>, 'property': 'child', 'action': '>', 'value': 1}
```

Comment: not exactly what I'm searching for. Reasons:
1. Here you usean instance of Parent, not the type itself;
2. In the Parent.__getattr__() you hardcoded Child, while there can be different classes (but I've got the idea will make a few attempts)

Comment: @VasylBratushka: then **be clearer in your question**. Why does it **have** to be a class object? You can always use a *metatype* to hook the `__getattr__` call, or just use `child = Child(Parent, 'child')` to hard-code the attribute.

Comment: `child = Child(Parent, 'child'` is definitely a working option and resolves all the issue, but smells really bad. Just imagine there's 10 different `Child` (or its descendants) properties in the Parent descendant - in each of them you'll have to put those 2 properties. Other than that - `Child` can have several other arguments in the `__init__`. I was looking for a solution without the 2 extra arguments. Sorry for not being clear enough in the question, will add this right now.

Comment: @VasylBratushka: the point is that if you want to include the information about parent (class name, attribute name) you have no choice but to pass that through.

Comment: this is exactly the reason why I asked this here. If there's no way to solve this without passing info through - the answer to this post is "no, it's impossible". Thanks for your efforts, I appreciate it.

Comment: @VasylBratushka: I recalled another technique and expanded on that; those allow you to ignore the attribute name and parent type in the `__init__` method.